# Why is the power adapter external (not built in) to the monitor?

Tags: heat, adapter, monitor, overheat

I am considering to tape this dangling box to the back of my PC monitor for easier manipulation - I carry the screen up and down every day.

[image]

However, my intuition has raised a red flag. Perhaps there is a good reason why the adapter is not built into the device itself.

The box is pleasantly warm to the touch, slightly warmer than the back of the monitor - nothing dramatic. Other than that no other reason comes to my mind - perhaps it is there just to make it easier to replace. Are there other reasons?

Comment: Also consider a second "box" for the other location.  Then you won't have to carry it at all.  And will have a spare if for some reason one fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see a few reasons why the manufacturer might have decided to use an external power supply :

- easier certification : certification for a product with hazardous voltages (ie mains) is "difficult", the same product at low voltages is far easier. So often manufacturers design their products for low DC voltages (often in the 12-24V range), and buy an of the shelve AC/DC converter that is already certified
- it enables to have different AC/DC converters for different main voltages/frequencies (there are coutries with 120V, others with 230V, 50 or 60Hz, and maybe even other combinations I do not know) : its easier to just pack a different AC/DC box, than to have different models of the monitor itself in production
- small argument : it might enable to use the monitor directly on DC systems (ex : solar powered) without adapter, or with a DC/DC adapter
- temperature might be an argument, but I don't think it's the main reason.

If you decide to tape it, make sure not to block the ventilation holes, nor to add too much thermal isolation. Gluing might be better than taping.

Answer (score 3):

Power adaptors are most often outside the main device they power for a number of reasons:

- Easy to sell in different countries (with different electricity and different regulations): just supply with different power cube
- Saves space in the housing
- Easier to design
- (and yes) easier to replace

As far as attaching to the back, your only real concern is if anything gets hot.  Often you can make a nice bracket out of a VESA mounting plate.